# how to filter similar values in a map?

Tags: elixir

I have a simple map and I want to filter the map which has similar values

Input

```
%{a: 1, b: 1, c: 2}
```

The search value is 1

Output

```
%{a: 1, b: 1}
```

Comment: are you looking for the most common value in a map, or do you know the value before filtering?

Comment: we know the value before filtering. Although now I'm interested to know most common value also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
%{a: 1, b: 1, c: 2} |> Map.filter(fn {_key, val} -> val == 1 end)
```

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#filter/2

Comment: This requires to hardcode the value (here 1). I assume the OP wanted something which works for all cases such as `%{a: 2, b: 1, c: 2} returning %{a: 2, c: 2}`.

Answer (score 1):

For Elixir 1.13 and above, you can use [`Map.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#filter/2) combined with [`match?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#match/2):

```elixir
Map.filter(map, &match?({_k, 1}, &1))
```

For earlier versions, and if you need to do multiple filters (according to the [note in the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.4/Map.html#filter/2)), you can combine [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) and [`Map.new/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#new/1):

```elixir
map |> Enum.filter(&match?({_k, 1}, &1)) |> Map.new()
```

In both cases the result is:

```elixir
%{a: 1, b: 1}
```

---

To find the most common value:

```elixir
map
|> Enum.group_by(fn {_key, value} -> value end)
|> Enum.max_by(fn {_value, group} -> length(group) end)
|> elem(0)
```

Output for your example:

```elixir
1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of diversity, here is the solution with `for` comprehension.

```elixir
for {k, v} <- %{a: 1, b: 1, c: 2},
    v != 1,
    into: %{},
    do: {k, v}

#⇒ %{c: 2}
```